# can't reinstall docker desktop on windows 10 pro

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

I have uninstalled Docker Desktop before; now when I try to re-install Docker Desktop, after I run the setup, I get the following message:

[image]

Then after pressing the yes or no button, I get the following form:

[image]

And installation is canceled.

I have checked the following registry path, but there isn't any key related to Docker Desktop:

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

**Please help me to solve the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

When you install each new version of Docker it does a full uninstall anyway, so give this a try and see if it doesn't help fully clean out the old Docker.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed

Comment: before, I full uninstalled docker desktop. by the way, I tried your solution but it didn't work, actually it didn't find any old docker version on my system.